# Assigning userform textbox entry to a variable in VBA procedure

Tags: vba, variables, textbox, userform

I have code that produces a userform, titled MaterialForm, which contains a textbox, titled txtGravity. My goal is to take the entry in the txtGravity box, check it to determine if it is numerical, and then store the numerical value as a variable to use in my procedure.

In the code that I am providing, the numerical check is working as intended and will only pass integers. The conversion from string to double is not working, however; and is storing the value "0" in my variable EnteredGrav.

Here is the code

```
Private Sub Cmd_Save_Click()
    With txtGravity   'Check for non-numerical or empty values
    If IsNumeric(.Text) = False Or Len(.Text) = 0 Then
        .Text = ""
        MsgBox "It must be a numeric value"
        .SetFocus
        Exit Sub
    Else  'Convert the text (string) to the data type double
        EnteredGrav = CDbl(Trim(txtGravity.Value))
    End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Thanks for any help you can provide!

Comment: How is EnteredGrav declared? Do you have `Option Explicit` on the top of the value? Probably you are having a grammar error. How is the code triggered?

Comment: It's declared as Double. And yes at the top of the module option explicit is stated. Does it need to be stated again before each sub? And sorry, what do you mean by how is the code triggered?

Comment: `Option Explicit` should be once only per module, on the top of the module. Thus it is ok. Concerning the triggered code - how do you call the code, how does it start, what do you do to start it? Can you make a [MCVE], which would be enough for anyone just to copy and paste it and to get the same error? If you provide this in your question, it would be answered quite quickly.

Comment: I updated the code with my sub info, but I'm not sure how to provide the code to produce the userform...if what I've provided isn't enough then thank you for attempting to help

Comment: you are still within your With block, EnteredGrav = CDbl(Trim(.Value)) so no need to specify txtGravity

Comment: What is the name of the userform after you produce it? What you need to do there is to ensure that the textbox that you are referring to is under the userForm that you produce. 

You can try to use this With UserFormName.txtGravity instead of calling it txtGravity

Answer (score 0):

Try these 3 lines:

```
Private Sub Cmd_Save_Click()

    Dim enteredGrav As Double
    enteredGrav = CDbl(Trim(Me.txtGravity.Value))
    MsgBox enteredGrav

End Sub
```

If it works, try building your code from there. Probably you are not entering the condition or not declaring correctly.